# Traffic in the same direction as yourself

Tags: antonyms

Is there a word in English to describe traffic, that goes in the same direction as yourself?

> The opposite of oncoming traffic?

Comment: Hm. Good question, actually. _Oncoming traffic_ is very common, of course, but now that I think about it, I don’t think I’ve ever had the need to describe the opposite. Can’t think of a familiar term for it, at least. The obvious option would be _parallel traffic_, but I’m not sure that’s actually used (and I suspect some might feel like that excludes people who are driving in front of or behind you).

Comment: 'Traffic' _is_ the stuff you're in, going in your direction. Who cares about the other side of the street?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words like "**confluent**", "**ongoing**", or "**onflowing**" traffic would be the opposite, addressing the precise question you ask. The use of "**ongoing**" to describe such a traffic pattern is probably common enough.

Other words like "**convergent**" or "**converging**" traffic might also be appropriate for certain specific uses.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/confluent

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/onflowing

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ongoing

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/convergent

Answer (score 1):

It's called *same-direction traffic*, as in [Modeling same-direction two-lane traffic for bridge loading](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167473011000427), whose abstract begins

> Many highway bridges carry traffic in two same-direction lanes, and modeling the traffic loading on such bridges has been the subject of numerous studies.

Another way to refer to same-direction traffic is to talk about driving, or walking, *with* traffic, as opposed to going *against* traffic.

Answer (score 0):

**following** traffic

As in:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71137?rskey=9pB1HA&result=1#eid4341837)

> 1971   Daily Tel. 22 Oct.   Hold straight until you are quite sure you
>   are in charge, flashing your brake lights if necessary..so as to warn
>   **following** traffic.

Comment: following traffic seems to mean the same-direction traffic behind you, but not the same-direction traffic to your side or ahead of you